# Calling function using label Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Working on a unit converter using Tkinter python, I want to change all other units according to the input unit but can't able to call that function which later configures other labels of units.

```
mainEntry = Entry(width=15,font="arial 15 bold")
mainEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

This Entry will get the input from user and other labels get update according to input without clicking any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable to `Entry` widget and use the `trace` method to detect any changes in the text and update labels accordingly.

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *

def change_lbl(*args):
   lbl['text']=var.get()

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.trace('w', change_lbl)

lbl = Label(root, text='Hello')
lbl.pack()

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```